# List<T> behaves as List<? super T>

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Reading an old book "Thinking in Java":

```
static <T> void writeExact(List<T> list, T item) {
    list.add(item);
}
static List<Apple> apples = new ArrayList<Apple>();
static List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
static void f1() {
    writeExact(apples, new Apple());
    // writeExact(fruits, new Apple()); // Error:   <<
    // Incompatible types: found Fruit, required Apple
}
```

When I ran the same program with Java 8, it ran fine - no error on passing `fruits, new Apple()` i.e. it is now also possible to put an `Apple` into a `List<Fruit>`, as you **expect**.

I want to know since which version this behavior has changed for the good. Evidently this new behavior does let us use a more compact generic form `List<T>` than the wildcard generic form `List<? super T>`.

More importantly, with this changed behavior, can we still maintain that ?

> "Supertype bounds *relax* the constraints on what you can pass into a
>   method"

Comment: The book is wrong (or you've misunderstood it). There was no version of Java that supported generics but wouldn't implicitly convert `Apple` to `Fruit` in order to satisfy that method signature.

Comment: Book clearly states there will be an error. But I get none. Page.no. 486

Comment: @SauravSahu *which edition* might help others let you know which Java version is it talking about!

Comment: Amazon lets you look inside [the 4th Edition (2006)](https://www.amazon.com/Thinking-Java-4th-Bruce-Eckel/dp/0131872486), which I've now done; and I agree with your understanding of it. It's just wrong. The authors messed up.

Comment: Ok. That should mean the quote `"Supertype bounds relax the constraints on what you can pass into a method"` 
is wrong too. As this example from Bruce Eckel was meant to demonstrate that.